# how to fix jquery scroll top animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

this code is working it will get me back from bottom to top but what it does not animate.
anyone can help me on this?

```
$('.topScroll').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop : "0px"},"fast");
});
```

Comment: Probably because you need to **include the jQuery library in your project**. By just having a `<a href="#top" class="topScroll">Go to top</a>` will perform the good old way... If my assumption is correct... So place right before the **closing** `</body>` tag `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script src="functions.js"></script>`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Internal linking wont create the animation effect that he desires

Comment: no it does not working

Comment: @AmoghHegde  please read my comment again. And again. If not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by slowing down the animation using microseconds as follows:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop : "0px"},1200);
```

Comment: @AliZain I Have created a working js fiddle for you see this 
https://jsfiddle.net/fm13bgxz/

Answer (score 0):

OK since seems like you're still in problems. The code you posted - **works**. Well, since you did not shared any HTML I can only suppose your exact markup and environment.

- Place jQuery and your code right before the closing body tag.
- If needed use `Event.preventDefault()`

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>topScroll - example</title>
  <style>
    body { height: 300vh; }
    .topScroll { position: absolute; top: 200vh;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <header id="top">
    <h1>Scroll down...</h1>
  </header>
  <a href="#top" class="topScroll">GO TO TOP</a>


  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on('click', '.topScroll', function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent browser doing default stuff on anchor/button click
      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: "0px"}, 500);
    });
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```